# How do I hide the HTML preview for a Stack Snippet?

Tags: support, feature-request, stack-snippets

I have a simple JavaScript code snippet that displays an alert message.

```js
alert("Hello world!")
```

Running the code snippet shows the alert as expected, but it also displays a white empty box below my snippet.

[image: Code snippet preview is a white box]

Since I don't have any HTML content to display, is there a way to hide the HTML preview for a Stack Snippet?

Comment: Probably an XY problem. You very likely shouldn't be using the `alert()` anyway. That and `prompt()` / `confirm()` are the only way to output things without using the rendered window. And `console.log()` is superior is pretty much all respects.

Comment: AFAIK that also contains the console output from the JS code. So unless Stack overflow checks your code, it doesn't know whether you output something or not.

Answer (score 3):

Lino is correct: the console is pinned to the bottom of the body of the HTML content.

You can't hide the HTML body while running the snippet but you can add some CSS so that it isn't pinned to the bottom of the page:

```js
console.log("Hello world!");
console.log("Hello world!");
console.log("Hello world!");
console.log("Hello world!");
console.log("Hello world!");
```

```css
body .as-console-wrapper {
  position: static;
  max-height: unset;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The size of that box is defined by the `<iframe>` on the page that forms the snippet, rather than the snippet itself.

This means that to change the size, the snippet's code would need to reach up to its `window`'s parent, find its own `iframe` on the page, and then adjust the element's appearance from there.

Unfortunately (or rather, fortunately, for reasons I'll get to), this is made impossible by browser cross-origin security mechanisms. Since snippets are, exactly for this reason, rendered on an alternate domain (https://stacksnippets.net), browsers do not let them access most information about, or modify, their parent page.

This is important and good, because it prevents abuse from bad actors who would otherwise be able to do nefarious things like post spam on your behalf. But, it also has the effect of making exactly what you're looking for effectively impossible.

Attempts to access or change any parent elements from a snippet will result in a security error:

```js
window.parent.document.getElementById('answer-421906').getElementsByClassName('snippet-result-code')[0].style.height = '0px';
```

That *doesn't* stop you, however, from making other local changes to the style of your snippet if you're so inclined:

```js
console.log('Dark mode snippet output!');

function printRand5() {
  var x = [];
  for (var i = 5; i > 0; i--)
    x.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*10000));
  return x;
}

console.log(printRand5());
```

```css
body{background:#1c1b1b!important}.as-console,.as-console-row,.as-console-row+.as-console-row>*,.as-console-row:after,.as-console-wrapper{border-color:hsl(210,4.5%,30.5%)!important}.as-console-wrapper{max-height:80%!important}.as-console{background:hsl(0,0%,17.5%)!important;color:#fff!important}@keyframes modifiedFlash{0%{background:rgba(0,204,255,.25)}100%{background:0 0}}.as-console-row-code,.as-console-row:after{animation:1s modifiedFlash!important}.as-console-row:after{color:rgba(255,255,255,.35)!important}
```

```html
<button onClick="console.log(printRand5())">Print Random 5 to Console</button>
```

But I would refrain from changes in practice unless you have a good reason for it in your answer (e.g. for a snippet with console-only output, setting the console's `max-height` to 100% can be very practical).